# Understanding IO monad in Scala

Tags: scala, io, monads

I'm learning scalaz and now I'm trying to understand the point of `IO` monad. I read [***this article***](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/04/28/monadic-io-laziness-makes-you-free.html) about IO monads and trying to run the simplest example myself:

```
val io = println("test").pure[IO]
println("before")
io.unsafePerformIO()
```

Yes, it works as expected. It prints

```
before
test
```

But I cannot catch the gist of the IO monad. What is the trick? Except "maintains substitution" as specified in the article I referenced.

The substitution does not seem too useful too me now. Could you please explain?

From what I can think. Imagine I have some traits:

```
trait Reader{
    def read(): List[Int]
}

trait Writer[T]{
    def write(t: T): Unit
}
```

So I have a reader which can read monadic values (`List` in my case). And then I need to write all values from the container somewhere else, performing some transfomation on them. Can IO monad be useful in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO is all around us, it is what makes programs actually useful, because we can't just compute pure expressions all day.

The IO monad attempts to address the problems in which make IO operations "unpure", such as fetching data from impure sources such as the network, for example.

IO, as for itself, is not referentially transparent. Think about a method returning `Unit`, like `println` for example. Let's try to substitute `println` for just `Unit` (or `()`), we won't get the same value, would we? Because `println` has the *effect* of printing to the console.

Using your example, imagine:

```
def write(t: T): Unit
```

What would happen if we substituted `write` with `()`? Well, there would be an effect of writing to the external source. However, if we used `IO[Unit]`, we wouldn't be breaking substitution.

To actually look at your problem, we'd need to combine the `List` monad with the `IO` monad, and as we know monads don't compose. We'll need to resort to some trickery with Monad Transformers:

```
import cats._
import cats.data.Nested
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

val nested = Nested(IO.pure(reader.read()))
val res: Nested[IO, List, IO[Unit]] = 
   Functor[Nested[IO, List, ?]].map(nested)(i => writer.write(i))

val ioResult = for {
  listOfIO <- res.value
  flattened <- Applicative[IO].sequence(listOfIO)
} yield flattened

ioResult.unsafeRunSync()
```

This isn't really pretty, and probably not as straight forward as just invoking an effectful operation returning `Unit`, but I'm sure there are better ways of going around monad composition than what I've created here for the purpose of the demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, but I have some question about transforming `IO[List[T]]`. Does `Scalaz` have some transformer for `IO` monad? Would be very convenient to use `IoT[T]`.

Comment: If you have `IO[List[T]]` then you need a `ListT` transformer, which scalaz does have.